# SQL Coding for Logical Operators question

Tags: sql

Q:
Using the retail. Inventory table, calculate what the total inventory would be for each product with 5 or less items in stock if all of the items on order were delivered immediately without any other sales taking place. The product_id for each product should be the first column in your results.

I need a sql code the one I am using is not working and I dont know another way to get the result my professor is asking for.

Expected:

```
product_id  ?column?
3   20
4   37
6   13
8   4
10  24
24  41
31  4
41  35
42  2
58  25
71  28
```

this is what I am using, but like I said it's wrong:

```
select product_id 
from retail.inventory
where total_on_hand <= 5;
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell how to get an "Expected result" when the original situation is unknown.  Also please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: _"need a sql code the one I am using is not working"_ You could show what you have so far, surely together with sample data either as two `Create Table...` together with some `Insert Into...` lines, or pasted as markdown tables, and show the desired result based on those sample data

Comment: Imagine you're talking to someone who doesn't know the inventory or orders table, who cdoesn't know which database engine you're using, and who can't see the sample data that leads to the expected result. 
Because you are. WIthout that, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity_on_hand + quantity_on_order) AS total_inventory_name
FROM retail_inventory_tablename
WHERE quantity_on_hand <= 5
GROUP BY product_id
```

You may try above

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity_on_hand + quantity_on_order) AS total_inventory
FROM retail.inventory
WHERE quantity_on_hand + quantity_on_order <= 5
GROUP BY product_id
```

This query first selects the product_id and calculates the total inventory for each product by adding the quantity_on_hand and quantity_on_order columns. It then filters the results to only include products with 5 or less items in stock, and finally groups the results by product_id to calculate the total inventory for each product.

Answer (score 0):

Took this class - the answer is:

```
SELECT product_id, total_on_hand + total_on_order

FROM retail.inventory

WHERE total_on_hand <= 5
```

Comment: Hello Amanda and welcome to SO. Could you please elaborate why this answer solves the question. Please try and provide a more complete answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).